# What license do you need to run MS Project on a MS terminal server?

Tags: windows-terminal-services, microsoft-project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We're running two terminal servers. On each of them we need MS Project 2007. What license is needed for MS Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to obatin a volume license so that the product does not need to activate. Then it's just a paper exercise of how many users and buy the appropriate number of licenses.